# i was trying to deploy external chaincode in my local network.but i get this error chaincode registration failed: container exited with 0"

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain

Error: endorsement failure during invoke. response: status:500 message:"error in simulation: failed to execute transaction d4f4c017ab15dbf45cd70edb4d50e90b5b8ee56e746df25a3cb15542fbe9eb5f: could not launch chaincode bankcc:1545554fd4e6ce41a4f0adc66ac39d2babd4a1aa634511521b19c243709b62ca: chaincode registration failed: container exited with 0".
**logs**
`2021-03-24 10:48:31.921 UTC [endorser] SimulateProposal -> ERRO 7b4 failed to invoke chaincode bankcc, error: container exited with 0 github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode.(*RuntimeLauncher).Launch.func1 /go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/runtime_launcher.go:118 runtime.goexit`

Comment: Check the log of the external chaincode. It seems like chaincode runtime error

Comment: Error starting Marbles02 chaincode: ccid must be specified  .this is the log of chaincode

Comment: It means you are not set the value of ccid variable in chaincode. You can set it by using environment variable (example: `ccid := os.Getenv("CHAINCODE_CCID")`)

Comment: **I did the same but still facng this error**                                                            `server := &shim.ChaincodeServer{
  
  CCID:    os.Getenv("CHAINCODE_CCID"),
   Address: os.Getenv("CHAINCODE_ADDRESS"),
  CC:      chaincode,
  TLSProps: shim.TLSProperties{
   Disabled: true,
  },`

Comment: and this is my peero logs `2021-03-25 04:53:55.840 UTC [endorser] SimulateProposal -> ERRO 046 failed to invoke chaincode bankcc, error: container exited with 0
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode.(*RuntimeLauncher).Launch.func1
 /go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/runtime_launcher.go:118
runtime.goexit`

Comment: Make sure you had set the value for CHAINCODE_CCID

Comment: **now facing this error** `could not launch chaincode bcc:f70cc312a9e95fe7914dcd5216624628dbdfb0d2304b8dcf2e1d8643f2451c0e: error starting container: error starting container: API error (404): network _byfn not found"`

Comment: maybe it related to the config of the docker network